# Calling object method inheriting from two classes

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, extends

I have three classes `A`, `B` and `C`.

`A` has a method `hello(self)`. `B` inherits from `A` and implements a new method `hello(self)`. `C` inherits from `B` and reimplements the method `hello(self)`.

Now if I create an instance `b = B()` and call `b.hello()` it calls as it should `B.hello(b)`.

The problem is that when I create an object `c = C()` and call `c.hello()` it calls actually `B.hello(c)` instead of `C.hello(c)`. Why is that?

My code looks like this:

```
class A:
    def hello(self):
        self.helloHandler()
    def helloHandler(self):
        print('class A method')

class B(A):
    def helloHandler(self):
        print('class B method')

class C(B):
    def helloHandler(self):
        print('class C method')

c = C()
c.hello()
```

This works but not mine. My code has several thousand lines at this point... Can't really post it but that is the point. I don't know what can be the problem. I use abcmeta if that matters for some obscure reason to force the child class to have some methods implemented.

Edit: I messed up two of my objects that look the same. Everything works as it should!

Comment: post your code.

Comment: If you are using a meta class, you should not be overloading the concrete methods defined in the parent class which were inherited from the abstract methods defined in the ABC.

Comment: Voting to close as the problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your problem.  Here is the setup as you have defined it, `B` inherits from `A` but overloads its method; `C` inherits from `B` but again overloads its method.

Creating an instance of `C` and calling `hello()` uses the correct overloaded method from `C`.

```
class A:
    def hello(self):
        print('class A method')

class B(A):
    def hello(self):
        print('class B method')

class C(B):
    def hello(self):
        print('class C method')

c = C()
c.hello()
# prints
class C method
```

Answer (score 0):

I got confused between all my classes. I have two objects that look very similar... everything works as it should.